# Private Settings managed packaged issue

Tags: security, ui

Have someone ever faced package named `Private Settings`? There is need to take a glance at the classes methods if it possible. I'm gonna use that one to reach out custom API but don't have a clear idea about how to set up my endpoint to get successful response

Comment: Anyone could have made this package; there could even be more than one with same name. Can you provide a link (appexhange or installer)?

Comment: actually, how can I get the link?